# Why are these vectors perpendicular?

Tags: general-relativity

I am reading [this paper](https://doi.org/10.1016/S0370-2693(00)01125-4) *The Bardeen model as a nonlinear magnetic monopole* by Eloy Ayón-Beato Alberto Garcı́a. A the end where the authors prove the that the weak energy condition is satisfied, they say that the vector
$$E_\lambda = F_{\lambda\mu}X^\mu$$
is space like because it is by definition perpendicular to the time like vector $X^\mu$.

Why are the perpendicular by definition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that $\mathbf F$ is the Faraday tensor, then it is antisymmetric by definition.  Therefore,

$$E_\lambda X^\lambda = F_{\lambda \mu}X^\mu X^\lambda$$

is the contraction of an antisymmetric object $F_{\lambda \mu}$ with a symmetric object $X^\mu X^\lambda$, which is equal to zero.

Comment: Yes F is the Farady tensor. I did not think of that, thank you

Comment: @mattiav27 Whoops, Faraday not Maxwell.  But yes, no problem.